# How could I use PLSQL code to send an XML file to my computer?

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

I am trying to collect data using a PLSQL code creating an XML file (I already did this part). However, the second part I need help with is trying to send the XML to my computer. Can somebody please provide me a code or example or link or video to see how this can be possible?

The code below demonstrates my code

D

```
ECLARE
  PART_NO_ VARCHAR(100) :='135449'; 
   l_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN l_refcursor FOR select 
     SUBSTR((select description from lora1app.ENG_PART_REVISION_REFERENCE
     where OBJSTATE = 'Obsolete' and PART_REV = 'OBS' and description like '%USE%' AND PART_NO =PART_NO_),
     1,6) AS Part_no__
     FROM  DUAL;

   l_xmltype := XMLTYPE(l_refcursor);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
END;


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <PART_NO__>OBS-US</PART_NO__>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sending the XML to your computer"? What does dbms_output.put_line give you that doesn't satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Boneist, thanks for your answer. When I wrote to send to my computer I meant to receive an XML in my document directory. I need this to happen automatically when the PLSQL code runs. By the way, the PLSQL  code described in my post will be a task that will trigger every hour. I need the XML to be sent every hour to my document directory.

Comment: Don't have time to go into detail with an answer but have a look at https://connor-mcdonald.com/2018/06/20/the-death-of-utl_file/ and especially what he is saying about spooling the output of a function to a file.

Comment: You can't send a file to your computer via PL/SQL **unless** your computer's directory is mounted on the database server and the database owner user has the necessary privileges to write to the directory. You could maybe send it as an email or store it in a table in the database, if the database server can't see your directory?

Comment: Bonesit. I found the following info